# How to create an overload for two already existing types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently trying to simulate the pipe in C++, where you give something as an argument to a lambda function through a pipe.

But when I to create the global overload on the operator | between the vector and the function pointer, i'm unable to redefine the operator since (I assume) you can't overload two primitive types.

Here is what i've been trying:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void operator |( int *vet , void(*func)(int)){
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 < i++){
        func(vet[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tab[10] =  { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 0, 1, 8 };

    tab | []( int x ) { cout << x*x << endl; };

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is  "error: ‘void operator|(int*, void (*)(int))’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type"

So, how would i go about overloading the | operator between an array and a lambda function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your overload makes no sense, considering that the `|` operator must return a value. You can't really change the basic aspects of operators.

Comment: Also, what you want is already implemented by the [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) function (or using the [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)).

Answer (score 1):

There is already a nice class representing function object in standard: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). You can use it to satisfy the requirement of operator overload ([see it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dF5WO0tcgIqovuE0)):

```
#include <functional>

void operator |( int *vet , std::function<void(int)> func){
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        func(vet[i]);
    }
}
```

However, the syntax you propose is really bad. It looks plain wrong to any reader who know C++. My first thought upon seeing this would be "*Someone made a typo and put `|` instead of `=`. Also, where's the type?*". Plus, you cannot really use it as pipe, because you don't return anything. Piping second call would return in call to `operator |(void, [function_type])`.

It would be bearable with named functions:

```
auto squarePrinter = []( int x ) { cout << x*x << endl; };
tab | squarePrinter;
```

but it's still confusing - it's not Bash code, is it?

Best and most readable solution is to use well-known functions and idioms from standard - [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), as suggested by Some Programmer Dude, or even plain `for` loop

```
#include <algorithm>

std::for_each(std::begin(tab), std::end(tab), []( int x ) { cout << x*x << endl; });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what i was looking for! As for the syntax, i agree it looks horrendous, but it was my assignment, so i had to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

After submiting my answer i had access to the solution which made me feel a bit stupid, here it is:

```
#include <algorithm>
 void operator | ( const auto& v, auto map ) {
  for_each( begin( v ), end( v ), map );
}
```